# Reading encrypted data from iDynamo Reader in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encryption

Does any know have experience with the [iDynamo Reader](http://www.magtek.com/v2/products/secure-card-reader-authenticators/iDynamo.asp)? This reader is using `DES-CBC` to encrypt card data. Is there anyone know how to decrypt this data?

Thank so much for your time.

Comment: Check weather this link may help u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152395/objective-c-read-file-encrypted-on-windows.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this too late but might help for someone else. So the solution is contact Magtek. If you buy Magtek device, ask them for lib. I have got libDS247.a from Magtek. Then import DS247.h to your code, implement the DS247Delegate. I provide here a sample for you-

```
(void)deviceDidConnect
{   
if (theAlertView.visible) 
    [theAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO]; 
}

- (void)deviceDidDisconnect
{
theAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hardware Not Connected!"
                                                 message:@"Please connect the device."
                                             delegate:self 
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[theAlertView show];    
[theAlertView release];
}

- (void)magneticCardReadStart
{
read = YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)magneticCardReadDidFinish:(NSString *)cardString
{
read = NO;

if (trackMode == 67)
{
    NSString *string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,20)];
    self.pan1 = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"] objectAtIndex:0];

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7+pan1.length,27)];
    self.name = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"] objectAtIndex:0];

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8+pan1.length+name.length,4)];
    self.ed1 = string;

    self.ed2 = @"";
    self.pan2 = @"";        
}
if (trackMode == 68)
{
    NSString *string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5,20)];
    self.pan2 = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:0];

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6+pan2.length,4)];
    self.ed2 = string;

    self.ed1 = @"";
    self.name = @"";
    self.pan1 = @"";

}
if (trackMode == 69 || trackMode == 70)
{
    NSString *string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,20)];
    self.pan1 = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"] objectAtIndex:0];

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8+pan1.length,27)];
    self.name = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"^"] objectAtIndex:0];

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9+pan1.length+name.length,4)];
    self.ed1 = string;

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(83,20)];
    self.pan2 = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:0];

    string = [cardString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(84+pan2.length,4)];
    self.ed2 = string;      
}
if (trackMode == 71)
{
    self.ed1 = @"";
    self.ed2 = @"";
    self.pan1 = @"";
    self.pan2 = @"";
    self.name = @"";        
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The should set trackMode as 67 as default, and the cardString is raw card data