# Objective-c: read file encrypted on Windows

Tags: objective-c, delphi, encryption

I am working on an OSX application using Objective-C, and one of the things I need to do is read text/xml files which were encrypted on a Windows machine using a simple bit-shift algorithm. The encryption code on the Windows side is fairly simple, in Delphi:

```
const
  EncryptKey : word = ????;
var
  InMS  : TMemoryStream;
  cnt   : Integer;
  c     : byte;
begin
  InMS    := TMemoryStream.Create;
  result  := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    InMS.LoadFromFile( FileName );
    InMS.Position := 0;
    for cnt := 0 to InMS.Size - 1 do
      begin
      InMS.Read( c, 1 );
      c := ( c xor not ( ord( EncryptKey shr cnt ) ) );
      result.Write( c, 1 );
      end;
  finally
    InMS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to properly read and decrypt this on the Mac side. I've tried various approaches to using NSData with no success whatsoever.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this would help you (simple xor encrypting):

```
-(void) decryptData :(NSMutableData *) data{
    unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *)malloc([data length]); 
    unsigned char magic[4] = {(currentCipher >> 24) & 0xff,(currentCipher >> 16) & 0xff,(currentCipher >> 8) & 0xff,(currentCipher) & 0xff};
    [data getBytes:bytes];
    int magic_pointer = 0;
    for (int i = 16; i < [data length]; i++) {
        bytes[i] ^= magic[magic_pointer];        
        if (magic_pointer == 3) magic_pointer = 0; else magic_pointer++;
    }
    free(bytes);
    [data setData:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes : bytes length: [data length] ]];
}
```

here:
`currentCipher` is your EcrytpKey, `^` xor. also shift right in C is `>>`, not operator is `!`.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will take the time to work through it and get back with results, questions, etc.

Comment: I finally had the time to sit down and get it working. You code was a great help. One note; the bitwise NOT operator is **~** not **!**. The code looks like this:

    NSMutableData *fileData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
    UInt16 currentCipher = ????;
    unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *)malloc([fileData length]); 
    [fileData getBytes:bytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < [fileData length]; i++) {
        bytes[i] ^= ~(currentCipher >> i);
    }
    [fileData setData:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes : bytes length: [fileData length] ]];
    
Thanks again.